# Menu and child menu in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

So i have in my database a table with id, id_parent, title and so on..
I need to create a list with sublists from that. I need some sort of recursive function but don't know how to do that in laravel..

I tried

```
class Goals extends Model {
  protected $table = 'goals';

  public function subgoals() {
    return $this->hasMany(SubGoals::class, 'id_category');
  }
}

class SubGoals extends Model {
  protected $table = 'goals';

  public function goals() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Goals::class, 'id_category');
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
$treeView = Goals::with(['SubGoals'])->get();
```

And view:

```
@foreach($treeView as $category)
  <li>
    <a href="#"> {{ $category->title }} </a>
      <ul>
         @foreach($category->subgoals as $subcategory)
           <li><a href="#">{{ $subcategory->title }}</a></li>
         @endforeach
       </ul>
 </li>
@endforeach
```

Didn't get the right result..
Maybe someone have a snippet..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to create 2 classes, just need one like your example Goal.

```
class Goal extends Model {
  protected $table = 'goals';

  public function subgoals() {
    return $this->hasMany(Goal::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
  }
}
```

then in the controller you need to "Query all parent Goals" like this:

```
$parent_goals = Goal::whereNull('parent_id')->get();
```

and finally in the view:

```
@foreach($parent_goals as $goal)
  <li>
    <a href="#"> {{ $goal->title }} </a>
      <ul>
         @foreach($goal->subgoals as $subgoal)
           <li><a href="#">{{ $subgoal->title }}</a></li>
         @endforeach
       </ul>
 </li>
@endforeach
```

that's it. hope that help's you.

Comment: You should also eager load subgoals, although I don't know how this can be achieved recursively. `$parent_goals = Goal::whereNull('parent_id')->with('subgoals')->get();`