# How can I compare 2 columns in the same table but not in the same row with Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, compare, where-clause

I want to display the values of columns with the same `menu_id` and the same `menu_parentid`. However, the array is empty when I execute in Postman. I want the values of columns with common `menu_id` and `menu_parentid` displayed in an array.

**Controller**

```
public function showMenu()
{
    return [
        'menus' => Menu::whereColumn('menu_parentid', 'menu_id')
            ->distinct()
            ->get()
            ->map(function ($item) {
                return [
                    'menu_id' => $item->menu_id, 
                    'menu_name' => $item->menu_name, 
                    'menu_icon' => $item->menu_icon,
                ];
            })
    ];
}
```

When I test on Postman, I get the following

```
{
    "menus": []
}
```

[Screenshot of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcYVw.png)

Comment: is it possible to have, same `menu_id` and `menu_parentId` ?

Comment: For example:
menu_id, name, menu_parentid
1, first, null
2, second, null
3. first-2, 1
4, first-3, 1
what will be your output?

Comment: THis code works for if a row has same 'menu_parentid' and  'menu_id', ie: If both menu_id and menu_parentid is 5 on a record, this solution will filter it out.

 from your screenshot, I can see there is no row with same 'menu_parentid' and  'menu_id',

Comment: I guess you should move from you menu_parentid and get its children. then loop over them.  You where query is leading this issue.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want But how get its children? You can help me plz ?

Comment: @gguney I try this one but it's not working also                                                                                    `      return[

        Menu::whereColumn('menu_parentid','menu_id')
        ->get()
        //->toArray()
        ->map(function($item){
            return [
                'menu_name' => $item->menu_name,
               // 'menu_parentid' => $item->menu_parentid,    
            ];                        
        })
    ]; `

Comment: you should not use whereColumn, they do not have to be de same. You have a problem with this where clause. Can you add your Menu model code too? There should be children relation to use.

Comment: @hasan05 yes to know each child belongs to which parent they should have the same id of the parent for exp: the parent has 2 as a menu_id then the children should have 2 as menu_parentid

Comment: @gguney I didn't make any change in the menu model . it contains only the useFactory()

Comment: I guess your main question is to display menus with their children right?

Comment: I think he has query problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Menu and child menu in laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929496/menu-and-child-menu-in-laravel-5-1)

Comment: @gguney yes I want the result like this : {"id" : 1                                                                   
                                                                   name: "Information"s,                                           
                                                                  "children": [   "id": 2, name:"Add Informations"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 }]}

Comment: @hasan05 I think too and I need to solve it ... any idea plz ?

Comment: @SirineBENHASSEN did you tried with eloquent relation?

Comment: @hasan05 no, I have juste one week experience with laravel and I don't know how to use it. Can you plz clarify it for me and sorry to disturb you

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. Instead of doing a query like that, you can make a relationship of the model with itself to get the `$menu->children` and then perform the array mapping the way you like. I don't want to write it out and guess how you like it to be displayed, so can you elaborate how you would like the array to be structured? Is it like this?:

```
"menus": [
             [parent_id1, child_id1], 
             [parent_id1, child_id2],
             [parent_id2, child_id3]
         ];
```

Or is it a different structure where the parent id's are all mixed with the children? I can only give you hints without you clarifying your structure.

Comment: the result should be like this : [
    {
          menu_parent_id= -1           (because these ones are the parents)
                 'Menu_name':'Dashboard'

     }
     'Children':[
{
        Menu_parentid != -1
       Or menu level =!1
}

     ]
]

Comment: Every parent has its own children

Answer (score 0):

You can you have to select a One to many relation in model.

```
public function childs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Menu::class, 'menu_parentid', 'menu_id');
}
```

Then, you can select items with this query,

```
Menu::with('childs')->distinct()->get();
```

Comment: thank youuu veryy much it seems very close from the final solution... Thank youuu

Comment: is it a acceptable answer ? anything more can we help you?

Comment: you are most welcome. have a good journey with laravel. :)

Comment: yes it's okey I will make some updates ...thank's for your generosity